# Is there any way to recover complete Application Insights messages that have been truncated due to excessive length?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-ad-b2c

I am developing a Azure AD B2C Identity Experience Framework application (our AAD B2C IEF POC as we like to call it - sadly we lost the Private Premium Preview (PPP) part).

In the custom log in policies you can add an Application Insights key for logging. We have done that, and used the tracing successfully when we have had issues. I have on those occasions used analytics.applicationinsights.io/.../ to view traces.

However, at times I have noticed that the message is truncated. I checked the character count of one such message and it was 32768 characters long. This logging often contains complete SAML assertions sent as XML and can be quite long so this does not seem to be something out of the ordinary.

So, my questions:

1. Is 32768 the max length of the Message column in Application Insights and is that why my tracing is truncated? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39628788/3604807) answer suggests that the max length part is correct, at least.
2. Is there a way to recover data rows that have been truncated? That is - can I access the raw data from some table storage or something similar?

This is most important when there are errors so any way to see B2C errors that is not reliant on the tracing can help. But it is also relevant when the policy is executed successfully and we wish to see the assertions "pre transformations". So:

3. Are there any other way of logging the complete Azure AD B2C flow?
4. Or can B2C error be logged separately?

I have very little experience in both AI and B2C so I may be misusing terminology here. Feel free to correct me or ask if anything is incorrect or unclear.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Yes**, the maximum length of the **Message** column in `Trace` is indeed **32768 characters**

   > Message Trace message.
   >
   > Max length: 32768 characters

Reference: [Trace telemetry: Application Insights data model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-data-model-trace-telemetry#message)

2. **No**, the Message column is bound by the Trace telemetry: Application Insights data model, hence the raw data point for Message column which you export out to some storage account will also have the maximum length

Answer (score 0):

3. **Yes**, the [user journey recorder/player](http://Using%20the%20user%20journey%20recorder/player)